# N fold Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning

I want to make 8 fold cross validation from the dataset. The dataset is the musical onsets annotated which has txt format at each songs.

[image]

How to make the another folder like called splits (the name of folder) which is contains 8 fold of songs. Each fold will be written as a txt format.

[image]

[image]

I need some code references to make 8 fold like that. Do I need use sklearn Kfold? And how to save each song like stated in the third picture?

Thank you.

Comment: data science stack exchange will be a better fit for this question.

Comment: This is off topic here, but there is example code already in the documentation for sklearn's kfold: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold